# How to represent different values for GET and POST methods in one serializer field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

How to change the Representation of Serializer for GET and POST Request?
Currently I am using The StringRelatedField in HotelSerializer which allows only readonly Feld I am unable to POST any Data because StringRelatedField does not maps with id in My case However id is manadotory For POST request.

If i use PrimaryKeyRelatedField for location in HotelSerializer than POST request will be executed and object will be saved Successfully

But hitting the api for GET request  For a Hotel with id 1 the response will be

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "asasa", "discription": "sasas", "location": 1, }
```

but i wanted the response should include the city name not the id of Location When i make GET Request

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "asasa", "discription": "sasas", "location": "delhi", }
```

or

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "asasa", "discription": "sasas","location": "Mumbai", }
```

models

```
class Location(models.Model):
    country =  models.CharField(max_length=60)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60,db_index=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10
class Hotel(models.Model):
    name =models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True)
    discription = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name='hotels')
```

serializer

```
class HotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location=serializers.StringRelatedField() #this line Cause Problem

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields= ('id','name','discription','location',)
```

Comment: I suggest you to make 2 serializers, one for insert or create and other for GET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your case you don't need any special field, DRF will provide `PrimaryKeyRelateField` by default for you:

```
class HotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields= ('id','name','discription','location',)
```

Also all fields in Django by default use not null constrain, e.g `null=False`. If you want to save a null value you should explicit write it in a field:

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name='hotels', null=True, blank=True)
```

`null=True` allows you to save a null value and `blank=True` make this field not required in a form validation.
**UPDATE:**
If you want to change representation of a serializer fields you could override `to_representation` method:

```
class HotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields= ('id','name','discription','location')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(HotelSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['location'] = instance.location.city
        return representation
```

Comment: null=True will cause saving hotes without referencing Location object but i wanted hotel must refer to location (mandatory)

Comment: @SyedMoinuddinShibli so what the problem? don't use `null` and `blank` and always pass `id` of location to a `HotelSerializer` `location` field

Comment: i am passing the id of Location in the form field but still i am getting the same error

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /api/hotels/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: hotels_hotel.location_id
Request informatio

Comment: @SyedMoinuddinShibli I update my answer, you don't need two separate serializers

Answer (score 1):

## models

```
location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True)
```

## serializer

```
class HotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Location.objects.all(), required=False) #this line Cause Problem

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields= ('id','name','discription','location',)
```

Comment: The reason Why I am not Using PrimaryKeyRelatedField() is becuase it will show only id of the locattion in the json where as wanted the String representation of Location objects based on city field...

It will return Json object as

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "asasa",
  "discription": "sasas"
  "location": 3,


}
but i want

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "asasa",
  "discription": "sasas"
  "location": Delhi,


}

Comment: Please update your question with full specification.